# Android: How to remove app from memory to retest first launch easily?

Tags: android, cordova

I build an Android App with Cordova. I added a splash screen. The default `SplashShowOnlyFirstTime` is true and I want to keep it like that.

But I want to actually test the user experience when opening the app the first time. When I do `cordova run android` it seems the app is reinstalled and treated like launching first time showing the splash screen.

On iOS I can double press the home button and remove apps from memory. I there the same function on Android? I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: Force Stop the application from Settings->Apps/Apps Manager.

Answer (score 1):

In `Settings`, you can find the `Application Manager`. Find your app, click on it and click the `Clear Data` button.

Comment: If you have persistent data like SharedPreferences, simply closing the app from the recent list will not reset it. Therefore if some screen navigation logic depends from these persistent values (for example showing the tutorial), you need to clear app data to reset the state similar to fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question but playing around for a bit:

A long press on Home and releasing lists the apps previously loaded. Swiping the app away causes the effect I was looking for. I am on Android 6.